# What does inject() do without arguments

Tags: ruby, inject, enumerable

I know the arguments for `inject()` between the parentheses are optional, so what happens when you leave them out? For example:

```
    [2, 4, 6, 8].inject{ |x, y|
      puts "x: #{x}   y: #{y}"
    }
```

outputs the following:

```
x: 2   y: 4 
x:     y: 6
x:     y: 8
```

Why does x start at 2? Shouldn't it start at nil? And why are there only 3 lines of output instead of 4?

Mainly: What does it do differently when it's given no arguments?

Comment: Interesting question, Zac.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> so what happens when you leave them out?

Then in the first pass, `x`, `y` will be set to the first 2 values from your collection. From the next pass onwards, `x` will be set to the value returned by the block, and `y` by the next element from the collection.

In your case in first pass `x` and `y` is set to as `2` and `4` respectively.

From the next pass onwards, `x` is set `nil`, as last statement in your block is `Kernel#puts`, which returns `nil` after printing the arguments you passed to it. But `y` is `6`, then `8`.

[`#inject`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject)

> If you do not explicitly specify an **initial** value for **memo**, then the **first element** of collection is used as the **initial value of memo**.

All is very expected as per the code.

---

Now suppose, you passed the initial value as - **11**, then output will be :-

```
x: 11   y: 2
x:     y: 4
x:     y: 6
x:     y: 8
```

Explanation is same here -

In this case in first pass `x` and `y` is set to as `11` and `2` respectively.

From the next pass onwards, `x` is set `nil`, as last statement in your block is `Kernel#puts`, which returns `nil` after printing the arguments you passed to it. But `y` is `4`, then `6` then `8`.

**NOTE :** After `x:`, when you are seeing nothing. Why ? As `nil.to_s` is empty string, i.e. `""`.